# AWD cars can't replace single tire?

Tags: tires, replace

I have 2-3 mm tread left on my tires. One of the tires has a sidebubble, and another has a leak. I went to belletire and they told me they can't just replace 1 tire, all 4 should be replaced because it is all wheel drive car and something about having uneven tread. Is this true?

They wanted 350 for the tire (https://www.continentaltire.com/product/procontact-gx-22545r18-95h-0). I am thinking I should just buy 4 new tires from costco for less than $1000

The tire is technically in warranty (45,000 miles) but the continental tire website seems to suggest sidebubbles aren't included

Comment: Several questions about this problem - shaving tires is also something to look for.

Comment: With 2-3mm tread left, and two tires with actual problems, it sounds like you should consider 4 new tires anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Most or at least many AWD vehicles require all 4 tires to be identical in size including tire wear. Otherwise the AWD system can be damaged. My 2005 Town and country requires same size in pairs, so if one tire needs replaced all I need to replace is the bad tire and the one across from it. Subaru's on the other hand say they require all 4 tires to perfectly match. Your owners manual will tell you what you need to know on this.